# Why this simple route doesn't work?

Tags: routes, playframework-2.0

[Play tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaRouting) shows a way to bind dynamic parameter to URL:

`GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)`

I want to do exactly the same thing in my app. But when I write `GET    /Category/getAttributes/:id controllers.Category.getAttributes(id)` and go to `http://localhost:9000/Category/getAttributes?id=4fce5fc51712ccf77afa7439` I receive `Action not found` error with my routes listed below. Proper route is there.

The question is: what am I missing? Routing in my PLay app works fine for other requests, this one is the only one with dynamic parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `String` type, I doubt if `4fce5fc51712ccf77afa7439` can be considered as a `Long`:

```
GET /clients/:id    controllers.Clients.show(id: String)
```

Of course don't forget to fix the type of `id` in your controllers and models

**Edit**: Ech, I missed second important change, URL for this route should be without `?id=`:

```
http://localhost:9000/Category/getAttributes/4fce5fc51712ccf77afa7439
```

Comment: Type was not a problem, it is `String` by default. URL was my problem, thanks for fixing!

Comment: Glad it works, of course using reverse routing you don't need to care about URL syntax, Play always create proper one or will throw an compilation error, which helps to ensure that you didn't miss something while 'manual' writing the path